# Django form widget - Add suffix while keeping the NumberInput

Tags: django, forms, widget, suffix

I have a form input on body height. I would like to put 'cm' after the height number (e.g. 183cm instead of just selecting 183) but keep it as a `NumberInput`.

Is it possible to add the suffix in the widget?

I have the following form.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Account

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body_height = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min':120,'max':230,'step':1, 'required':False,})


    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['body_height','otherfields']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['body_height'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your height (centimeters)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class NumberInputWithSuffix(forms.NumberInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return super().render(name, value, attrs) + mark_safe(' cm')


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body_height = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=NumberInputWithSuffix(
            attrs={'min': 120, 'max': 230, 'step': 1, 'required': False, }
        ),
        input_formats=['%d'], format='%d cm'
    )

    # your code ...
```

You can extend the default `NumberInput`'s render method and change the default Html.